# LEFT join returns only NULL for right side

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, left-join

I am facing a problem with a `join` query with two conditions. the problem is that the query only gives back the left site, whereas the right site only contains `NULL`. I checked that the types of the data match. What could be going wrong?

```
SELECT t2.YEAR_NUMBER
    ,t2.WEEK_NUMBER
    ,t2.STOCK_RIC
    ,t1.SENT_POS_WEIGHTED
    ,t1.SENT_NEUT_WEIGHTED
    ,t1.SENT_NEG_WEIGHTED
    ,t1.OBSERVATIONS
    ,t1.AV_W_RELEVANCE
    ,t1.AV_W_LNKD_CNT1
    ,t1.AV_W_ITEM_CNT1
INTO res
FROM Structure2016 t2 left JOIN
     pre t1
     ON t1.WEEK_NUMBER = t2.WEEK_NUMBER AND t1.STOCK_RIC = t2.STOCK_RIC
ORDER BY STOCK_RIC, WEEK_NUMBER
```

EDIT: brief example of how tables look like and should look like. The STOCK_RIC columns are currently of type char(13)

```
    TABLE Structure2016:

    STOCK_RIC       YEAR   WEEK_NUMBER
    JPM.N           2016    1
    JPM.N           2016    2
    JPM.N           2016    3



    TABLE pre:
    STOCK_RIC    WEEK_NUMBER  SENT_POS_WEIGHTED
    JPM.N           5             0.1
    JPM.N           3             0.9
    JPM.N           1             0.1
    JPM.N           10            0.1

    Result should then look like
    STOCK_RIC        WEEK_NUMBER  SENT_POS_WEIGHTED
    JPM.N               1              0.1
    JPM.N               2              NULL
    JPM.N               3              0.9
```

Comment: that's what's supposed to happen if there's no matching records on the "right" side of the query. you've got a 2-component `and` condition in the join, which means BOTH of those separate conditions have to be "true" to match a record on the right.

Comment: What is your desired input and output?

Comment: Suprised? Left join is for that.

Comment: It sounds like you want an [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) instead.

Comment: If you "Only" get back the left side with the left outer join.  The data you are joining on does not match.  When you shift to an inner join you will get nothing if this is the case.  Review the things you are joining on and insure they "both" match and return a match.  I sometimes like to do a "full outer join" to see how the data is actually matching or not matching up.  If what you are joining on is not a match.  You will see all nulls on one side for one table and all nulls on the other side for the other table.

Comment: Data may "match" when you look at it visually, but not match according to the way Sql looks at it.  You may want to convert the data to character data, look at it, and match it up then if this is the issue.

Comment: ok thanks for the comments so far.. i did some tests with some with some where statements and these worked all fine... if i do a full outer join i get only the right site and null for the left. inner join returns nothing... thus data really dosnt match - which it should shit it has the same origin. is there any way to align the data?

Comment: Please give us the sample data and expected output

Comment: please see edit

Comment: What is current output of query

Comment: it returns NULL for all values of SENT_POS_WEIGHTED

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, I constructed the sample you provided and here the result

```
STOCK_RIC   WEEK_NUMBER SENT_POS_WEIGHTED
JPM.N         1               0.1
JPM.N         2               NULL
JPM.N         3               0.9
```

the code I used was

```
declare @table table(
     STOCK_RIC varchar(10),
     YEAR int,
     WEEK_NUMBER int
  )
 declare @pre table(
    STOCK_RIC varchar(10),
    WEEK_NUMBER int,
    SENT_POS_WEIGHTED decimal(3,1)
  )

  insert into @table(STOCK_RIC,YEAR,WEEK_NUMBER)
  select 'JPM.N',2016,1
  union
  select 'JPM.N',2016,2
  union
  select 'JPM.N',2016,3 

  insert into @pre(STOCK_RIC,WEEK_NUMBER,SENT_POS_WEIGHTED)
  select 'JPM.N',5,0.1
  union
  select 'JPM.N',3,0.9
  union
  select 'JPM.N',1,0.1
  union
  select 'JPM.N',10 ,0.1


  select t.STOCK_RIC,t.WEEK_NUMBER,p.SENT_POS_WEIGHTED
  from @table t
  left join @pre p on t.STOCK_RIC = p.STOCK_RIC and t.WEEK_NUMBER = p.WEEK_NUMBER
```

It seems the problem is not in the code you posted

Comment: indeed, thanks for checking that. i suppose there is something wrong with the column STOCK_RIC - could it be the format?

Comment: try to make inner join on this field only STOCK_RIC, any output?

Comment: maybe a collate problem, try inner join as follows: `inner join cast(t1.STOCK_RIC as varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS) = cast(t2.STOCK_RIC as varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS)` , any result?

Comment: still nothing :( i collated the two columns completely, but the results remain the same :(

Comment: what else could be the problem here? i am really stuck

Comment: if i am in your place, i will try ltrim(rtrim(STOCK_RIC)) maybe the fields contains spaces, if it didn't work then i will copy one value from first table and paste it in the second table, your inner join statement should return result if it is only on one column STOCK_RIC

Comment: it was really the case that some empty spaces were stored in STOCK_RIC. But ltrim(rtrim(STOCK_RIC)) did not work... i dont get why. i am sorting the values now manually in excel using vlookup. could it be a bug in sql?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can tell it will throw an error is that your `order by` clause. You need to specify `t.STOCK_RIC, t.WEEK_NUMBER` or `p.STOCK_RIC, p.WEEK_NUMBER`.